# product export and import using xml

Tags: import, migration, e-commerce, plugin-wp-e-commerce, export

I am use eCommerce plugins for the eCommerce support in wordpress

I am export my all product using `Tools->export` from my `http://localhost/first` wordpress site and i am try to import in my wordpress another site like `http://localhost/second`

and it is not give any error but not display product main image.

I am try to debug the code and i found the problem in xml attribute name like

```
<wp:postmeta>
 <wp:meta_key>_wpsc_product_metadata</wp:meta_key>
 <wp:meta_value>dtails</wp:meta_value> 
</wp:postmeta>
```

and

```
<wp:postmeta>
 <wp:meta_key>_thumbnail_id</wp:meta_key>
 <wp:meta_value>253</wp:meta_value>
</wp:postmeta>
```

i am not understood how can i change this two attribute value

please help me

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're exporting from a localhost installation, the other installation cannot import images because it technically needs to be 'online' for the new installation to download the images off the older one.

The easiest thing to do would be to migrate the old site to an online installation. You can read about [how to move Wordpress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress) in the Codex. After it's online, the new localhost installation and other installations will be able to properly import the older site including its images.